# Submit form using jquery and submit button

Tags: jquery, html, submit

I want to submit form using a input type submit with name `checkEvent`, how can I do that,
`$('#test').click()` doesn't do that and if I use `$('#checkFoem').submit()` I don't get `$_POST['checkEvent']` on the server side.

```
<form method="post" action="" id="checkFoem">
    <input type="hidden" value="{EVENTID}" name="eventId" />
    <input type="submit" value="{#CHECK}" id="test" name="checkEvent" class="confirm" />
</form>
```

Comment: Why the need for the jQuery, the default submit for the form would achieve that?

Comment: What happens if you press on the submit button, does it work then?

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#checkFoem").submit();
```

This should be enough.

Comment: He states in his question that the submit alone is insufficient, as he wants the value of the submit button parsed through.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a hidden input to get whatever value you wanted to catch in the submit?

Comment: What if you have two submit buttons, and you want to see which one is pressed.

Comment: 2 submit buttons? Crazy talk :p

Comment: Why not bind to a click of the submit button and then do form.submit() inside the handler?

Comment: 2 submit buttons is a standard scheme when you have for example an edit, save and delete button in a same form, then only an button value can tell the difference.